# field validation on publishing the website

Tags: asp.net, publish, web-deployment

On my development PC, I created simple form with 3 text boxs and a submit button. I added validation to the text boxes and time to last text box.

```
<asp:TextBox
        ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ForeColor="#FF9999"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<br />       
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
        ForeColor="#FF9999"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<br />         
<asp:TextBox
        ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
        ForeColor="#FF9999"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

(and added now() to textbox3)

On submitting the form, when running on local host (my development PC), the validation executes fine with no post back (means I don’t see changes on time on text box3). However, when I upload all the files to the server, upon submitting I see validation but it happens after post back which I see a new time on textbox3. Also I get this JavaScript error:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
        new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
            &quot;Button1&quot;,
            &quot;&quot;,
            true,
            &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;,
            false, false))" id="Button1" />
```

What am I doing  wrong?  Should the solution be under release or debug?

Comment: What do you mean by **time** and **now()**? *Please do not write long run-on sentences. It is hard to read.*

Comment: sorry, well, I mean when I run this on my develpment PC once you click on button, validation works and works fine and time on textbox2 I does not change,

Comment: but when I move all the folders to the server, after clicking the button, validation shows up but the times changes, means that the form gets submitted and then validation happens.